# Unpacking a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I am extracting a dictionary that's giving me this output:

```
mylist= [[u'Ann', u'jOhn', u'Clive'], [u'124street', u'32B', u'16eve', u'beach']]
```

When I try to separate it into two, I get a `ValueError`:

```
nest1, nest2 = zip(*mylist)

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Ultimately I need something like this:

```
nest1=['Ann', 'jOhn', 'Clive']
nest2=['124Street', '32B', '16eve', 'beach]
```

I found `zip(*mylist)` within [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149290/7172003).

Comment: Why not just `nest1, nest2 = mylist` ?

Comment: @khelwood it worked many thanks

Answer (score 5):

`*zip` is meant to be used to unpack lists of tuples. In your case, there is no unpacking needed to be done, so just unpack the list itself:

```
In [473]: x, y = [[u'Ann', u'jOhn', u'Clive'], [u'124street', u'32B', u'16eve', u'beach']]

In [474]: x
Out[474]: ['Ann', 'jOhn', 'Clive']

In [475]: y
Out[475]: ['124street', '32B', '16eve', 'beach']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mylist= [[u'Ann', u'jOhn', u'Clive'], [u'124street', u'32B', u'16eve', u'beach']]
nest1 = mylist[0]
nest2 = mylist[1]
print("nest1={}".format(nest1))
print("nest2={}".format(nest2))
```

Outputs:

```
nest1=['Ann', 'jOhn', 'Clive']
nest2=['124street', '32B', '16eve', 'beach']
```