# How to plot with matplotlib when both dependent and independent variables are in the same list

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Imagine this piece of code where `X` is the independent variable, and `Y` is the dependent variable and is equal to `X ** 2`:

```py
X = [1, 2, 3]
Y = [1, 4, 9]
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

What if both of my variables were in the same list:

```py
li = [[1, 1], [2, 4], [3, 9]]
```

The first element of every nested list is `X`, and the second one is `Y`; how should I plot this?

*I'm pretty sure someone already asked this question, but I didn't know what to search and didn't found an answer.*

Comment: `X, Y = zip(*li)`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149278/splitting-a-nested-list-into-two-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose the list of lists prior to plotting it:

```
X, Y = list(zip(*li))
plt.plot(X, Y)
```